# What's the difference between using "git diff <commit1> <commit2>" and "git diff <commit1>..<commit2>"

Tags: git

I want to display the changes made since HEAD~3 until HEAD~1. What's the difference between using two dots like `git diff HEAD~3..HEAD~1` and not using them like `git diff HEAD~3 HEAD~1`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+double+dots

Comment: No difference. They are the same.